# Using fetch to get a simple string from flask api

Tags: python, reactjs, flask, fetch

I am trying to connect my flask api to my react app and all I want from that is to display the string I returned from the flask on react app.

In doing so, I used useEffect(), but my variable in react is not changed but just keeps the original state. When I use console.log to see the value that I am passing to the variable, it shows an error saying "Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0".

App.js looks like:

```
import React, {Component, useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import './App.css';


function App() {
  const [block, setBlock] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/video').then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
      setBlock(data.text);
      console.log(data.text);
    });
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <p>Text: {block}</p>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}


export default App;
```

part of flask(flask.py):

```
@app.route('/video')
def video():
    return {'text': text}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you include the full response you're seeing from the network tab in your browser when the request is made?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to return JSON from a Flask route use [`flask.jsonify`](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.json.jsonify).

```
from flask import jsonify
@app.route('/video')
def video():
   return jsonify({'text': text})
```